# Object seems rotated altough it isn't?

Tags: objects, transforms

I have encountered a weird issue; Blender shows that both of my objects have 0 on all rotation grids but when I look at them closely I can see that one of them is rotated, I haven't changed any of its rotation settings when I made both of these objects so default for both of them should be 0.

Visualization:

[image]
[image: Notice it says 0 0 0 on the rotation]
[image: Same thing here, but the object is for some reason still not aligned]

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what's going on from screenshots alone. If you [post your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be due to the object's origin is far off (when you move/edit the size in edit mode and not in object mode, the origin stays in the same place and can cause some artifacts like this), you can always take the vertices that don't align, press G to grab them, then Z to pull them only on the Z axis, now you can snap them on the vertices on the other side:
[image]